# Is this a good practice to avoid popup content displayed in a new tab or window?

Tags: php, popup, referrer

I have pages with photo thumbnails, let's say the script is thumbnails.php. Each icon has a link to popup.php?id=nnn that opens in a pop-up window to display a larger image and some info.

I don't want a user going directly to domain.com/popup.php?id=nnn to get the popup small content in a whole window or tab.
So this script first checks if the referrer is the page containing the thumbnails.
If not, descrption.php?id=nnn is opened.  This page is designed to fit a regular screen with extended info.
I did in this way mainly thinking in web crawlers.

Is this a good practice?

Comment: Because of this Google WMT tells me there are duplicated title tags from both popup.php?id=nnn and description?id=nnn despite they are not the same. Edit: I realize I can add popup.php to robots.txt (disallow) mmmm, not sure if it is good thing to do

Comment: I don't see how adding popup.php to disallow would hurt, you don't want google attempting to index the results of the script. Unless you want google to scrape the images?

Answer (score 1):

Many projects that I have worked on over the last 18 months have gone away from opening new windows or tabs altogether. Instead they use the [Jquery Dialog (modal mode)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) to display images, html descriptions, or other attribute information.

This allows the user to stay on the same page without the risk of causing them to bounce if they accidentally close the wrong window or tab, or they just forget to go back to your site via the original window.

Comment: I've been seeing this method from a long time . I'm still not convinced because of some reasons are long to explain here. Anyway I'll think about it again

I don't understand your last point. A user may accidentally close a popup but the main page is still there, he can open it again.

Comment: Ahhh sorry, was distracted by the "to get the popup small content in a whole window or tab." line.

Comment: Also the title of the question infers that you were asking about new windows and tabs.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear. This is not my usual language. BTW, despite I checked in my profile to receive notices about new answers I am not getting any.

Comment: No new answers have been posted yet, is probably why.